# Python - SPARQLWrapper badformed (semantic web)

Tags: python, sparql

I have this **`SPARQL query in python`**

```
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql",returnFormat="json")

sparql.setQuery(''' 
SELECT DISTINCT *
where {
    []  foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wikiID.
    FILTER (regex(?wikiID, "(\\W|^)World(\\W|$)","i")) . 
}
ORDER BY ?wikiID
limit 50 
''')    

queryResult = sparql.query().convert()

print json.dumps (queryResult, indent= 2,  separators=(',',':'))
```

But no results back.

```
(SPARQLWrapper.SPARQLExceptions.QueryBadFormed: 
 QueryBadFormed: a bad request has been sent to the endpoint, 
 probably the sparql query is bad formed)
```

On http://dbpedia.org/sparql the query is ok, where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution

```
sparql.method = 'GET'

sparql.setQuery(''' 
    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM <http://dbpedia.org>
    where {
    []  foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wikiID.
    FILTER (regex(?wikiID, "(\\\W|^)World(\\\W|$)")) . 
        }
    ORDER BY ?wikiID
    limit 50 
''')
```

Comment: Even if that code works for you, what was the actual problem?  Your query code was legal (aside from the missing foaf prefix, which this code *doesn't* fix).  Is it the additional `sparql.method = 'GET'`?

Comment: GET method is for SELECT queries, POST for INSERT/DELETE. the problem was the regular expression (\W|^); in SPARQL you must set another escape (\\W|^), on python another one escape (\\\W|^)